# Python requests equivalent of cURL command

Tags: curl, python-requests, put

I have a cURL command I run like this:

```
curl -F "media@video.mp4"-X PUT http://API_URL/path/to/put
```

And it works.

In python I have done the following:

```
import requests
url = 'http://API_URL/path/to/put'
files = {'media': open('./video.mp4', 'rb')}
r = requests.put(url, headers=headers, data=files)
print(r.text)
```

And get the response from the server is that it did not think I tried to upload any media. I have seen similar questions asked on here for doing this with POST requests but no solutions for PUT request, the need for being a PUT request is out of my control.The solution can be using libcurl in C, or any other python library but I do not want to do system(); from c with the cURL command.

Comment: Use the `files` parameter? Also, what's in the `headers` dict?

Comment: I have tried the files parameter with no difference, I just left out what I'm using for headers due to the API key needing to be obviously not put on the internet, I am getting passed the servers auth with a valid API key in the headers.

Comment: Yes, of course. Can you copy-paste your actual code (except the key)? Your python code should produce the same request as your curl command, if you use the `files` parameter.

Comment: I retried it using files it is working. I could have sworn I tried that earlier but who knows. Thanks